# Reset battery status after changing battery?

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-nexus, charging

If I plug in the charger of my Galaxy Nexus, I'm able to replace the battery without switching the phone off. However, the battery status does not adjust to the new battery. For example, if I replace an empty battery with a fully charged one, the phone still shows an empty battery symbol.

Is there any way to adjust the battery status to the new battery?

When changing the battery while the phone is running, do I risk breaking the phone or the battery in any way? For example, if the phone thinks the battery is empty while it's actually full, do I risk to overcharge the battery if I connect the phone to a charger?

**Edit**:

I just noticed the following:

If I enter `*#*#4636#*#*` and select battery info, it displays a charging state of 100 after changing to a new battery. So the phone notices that the battery was changed. I'd just like to see that as well in the battery icon in the notification bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to reboot. Your battery won't be damaged by hot removing it. It has an internal circuit to prevent overcharge. Removing it while (dis)charging doesn't matter.

See [this post](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/FV3LVtdVxPT) from Android developer Dianne Hackborn.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link doesn't work for me, it looks broken...

Comment: link is fixed now